# dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

While upgrading my Ubuntu 16.04 Laptop I faced an error like below

```
﻿Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic (4.4.0-93.116) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-93-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-93-generic
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-93-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.93.98); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: It looks like this is [a possible bug in Plymouth](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1592405), although it has not been confirmed. Based on the title of the bug report, I would guess that installing the DejaVu fonts manually (by installing the package `fonts-dejavu`) might fix the issue.